# Eclipse .cproject programmatic creation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I've got Eclipse plugin code that programmatically creates an Eclipse project. The gist of it is here: [Programmatic creation of Eclipse project in the Eclipse workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75833893/programmatic-creation-of-eclipse-project-in-the-eclipse-workspace) (the code shown on this post is the same coding project as I am currently asking about).

In my use-cases, the projects created are always C/C++ projects.

I initially thought just adding a `CNature` to the instance of `IProjectDescription` would suffice when it is assigned to the instance of an `IProject` but this does not appear to be enough. The code runs seemlessly (no errors), but I'm rightly or wrongly expecting a `.cproject` file to be created also. I've tried various things to create this, including this:

```
IProject newProject = workspace.getRoot().getProject(projectName);
try {
       newProject.create(newProjectDescription, monitor);  // create Eclipse project
       CoreModel model = CoreModel.getDefault();           // get default CDT model
       ICProject cproject = model.create(newProject);      // create CDT model for project
    } catch (CoreException ex) {
       // <snipped - does some logging>
    }
```

...with this later...

```
try {
        newProject.open(monitor);
        newProject.setDescription(newProjectDescription, null);
        cproject.save(null, true);  
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // <snipped - does some loggging>
    }
```

...to no avail.

The programmatically created project is a duplicate of an existing project. The existing project was imported in to Eclipse using the "Existing Projects into Workspace..." option. I did not specify a toolchain for it. Neither does it actually have anything like make files in its structure, it's purely C and C++ files only. Yet, when I right-click on each and examine the context menu, the original manually imported one has "Build Project", "Clean Project" and "Make Targets". Similarly, if I compare properties, the original has a "C/C++ Build" section, but the programmatically created one lacks this. The same is true in that the original has a `.cproject` file and the programmatically created one does not.

I wish them to be identical such that the programmatically created one has the items I mention it currently lacks, in order to have the same context menu, "C/C++ Build" section in its properties and the important `.cproject` file.

I suspect it is the presence of the `.cproject` file that makes the difference in IDE behaviour, and I wish to know how to ensure that gets created also.

**UPDATE 1:**

Based on @nitind idea of tracing in to Eclipse code, I have discovered that the `.cproject` file is written from package `org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml` and class `DesSerializationRunnable`, which has the following function (given it implements `Runnable`):

```
public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
  JobChangeAdapter notifyJobCanceller = new NotifyJobCanceller((NotifyJobCanceller)null);
  try {
    Job.getJobManager().addJobChangeListener(notifyJobCanceller);
    ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().run(new IWorkspaceRunnable() {
        public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
        }
    }, (ISchedulingRule)null, 1, (IProgressMonitor)null);
    XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.this.serializingLock.acquire();
    LanguageSettingsProvidersSerializer.serializeLanguageSettings(this.fDes);
    XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.this.projectModificaitonStamp = XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.this.serialize(this.fDes.getProject(), ".cproject", this.fElement);
    ((ContributedEnvironment)CCorePlugin.getDefault().getBuildEnvironmentManager().getContributedEnvironment()).serialize(this.fDes);
  } finally {
    XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.this.serializingLock.release();
    Job.getJobManager().removeJobChangeListener(notifyJobCanceller);
  }
}
```

and specifically the line referring to ".cproject" writes the file.

I now just need to see how this gets called, and deduce if I can mimic it in my scenario, or better still, find a way to re-use this Eclipse code.

Comment: Have you looked at the code that executes when finishing the new project wizard for that kind of project? If you set a breakpoint in the implementation of one of the methods you're calling yourself, you should find it relatively quickly when you run the wizard.

Comment: @nitind The original project import was completely manual. A user creating/importing a project via Eclipse Wizard is not going to trigger anything in my plugin, and likewise, my plugin doesn't trigger any Eclipse wizard.

Comment: @nitind That being said, I've managed to deduce ```org.eclipse.core.cdt.CCorePlugin``` class has its ```createCDTProject``` function called, so I have managed to get a breakpoint on that and am currently tracing to see what it does differently to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after as much tracing in to Eclipse as I could do, I found some but not all things that I needed to directly create a project with a `.cproject` file.

However, after finding that there are some project conversion functions on the Eclipse `CCorePlugin` class, I decided to try those (at the time mixed in with some other code). Ultimately, I only needed to call a single method after calling `open(...)` on my `IProject` reference.

I discovered that converting to a `CProjectNature` is only suitable for C and that I need to also cover C++. Converting solely to a `CCProjectNature` (note the extra C at the front) would add both types of nature to the project. It also ultimately calls the code I put in my question update, so writes the `.cproject` file. I checked the context menus and and the project properties and they now match what the Eclipse import wizard was producing.

So short version is this original code:

```
try {
      newProject.open(monitor);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
      // <snipped - do some logging>
}
return newProject;
```

...becomes...

```
try {
      newProject.open(monitor);
      cdtCorePlugin.convertProjectToNewCC(newProject, DEFAULT_PREFERENCE_CONFIG, monitor);
    } catch (CoreException e) {
      // <snipped - do some logging>
}
return newProject;
```

where `cdtCorePlugin` is simply defined earlier as:

```
CCorePlugin cdtCorePlugin = CCorePlugin.getDefault();
```

and `DEFAULT_PREFERENCE_CONFIG` is a constant defined as:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_PREFERENCE_CONFIG = "org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.configurationDataProvider";
```